# I cannot resolve symbol 'maps' java android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to import android-map-utils to my project.

I tried import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
It's tell me that Cannot resolve symbol 'maps' 
I use 3.5 Gradle Version and sdk version API 25

How did i do 
build.gradle I added this code

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

And I added this code below in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*"/>
```

But it can't still it

How to solve this problem

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? Can you show the error?

Comment: I using android studio 3.4.1? 
error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist

Comment: I don't know why I can't use library from repositories.
I solve problem by download api .jar from internet then import it to my project. 
It's work

Comment: You need to update your ```gradle```.  Also yo need to set```targetSDK``` version to newest. ```compile``` command has been replaced by ```implementation``` long time ago (more then year ago). And after that you can import library right (like i show you in answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Maps dependency too:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0`

Comment: I added but still can't use com.google.android.maps

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem by import manual library

`compile files('android-google-map-api.jar')`